# Gemara relating to Yeshua Hanotzri

Tags: talmud-gemara, christianity

Does anyone have a list of all the places where Yeshua Hanotzri is mentioned in the Gemara (and was redacted because of the Christian censor)?

I found theses two places:

1. Sanhedrin 43a
2. Sanhedrin 107b

Comment: Yeshu* not Yeshua, at least in the Gemara text. You can find all the citations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_the_Talmud

Comment: @Yehuda sounds like an answer, could you write it up for the sake of the perpetuity and utility of Mi Yodeya?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120388/does-the-talmud-say-that-jesus-writhes-in-excrement-and-mary-was-a-prostitute/120503#120503

Comment: @Yehuda it should be noted that MS Harav Herzog of Sanhedrin, widely considered one of the best manuscripts of Sanhedrin (in terms of preservation of the original version), has the version ישוע. But other manuscripts have ישו, at least in the two places brought by the OP.